# Error message with dissolve in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dissolve

After about 10 hours of dissolving, QGIS gives me this message :-(
[image]

Any ideas, what this means and maybe how to correct?

Comment: Can you do as the error says and show us the logs? you can find the python log when you press the 'messages' button on the bottom right.

Comment: I suspect it drained your system — I'd try in smaller batches.

Comment: @HDunn: thanks for the hint - maybe next weekend I have the time for another try and then I will look into the log

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: 10 hours, ouch... I don't know what is the purpose but maybe Rasterize and Polygonize back in some reasonable resolution should be much faster and fitting your needs?

Comment: @ndawson : I am using the latest release version  of 2.16  64 bit for windows . As I can see now there is already a version 2.18 I will install this newer version and try again

Comment: @Kurt - Looks like a lot of data to process. Maybe you can consider exporting the layer to **PostGIS** and using tools like [ST_Union](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html)?

Comment: Ok, on 2.16.4 try adding a temporary column to the layer with all equal field values. Then dissolve using that field.

Comment: @Joseph: thanks for the tip:

 CREATE TABLE mergedlayer AS
 SELECT ST_Union(geom) 
 FROM burgenlandzsp;

did the dissolve in 10 seconds !! btw there are 382 polygons in the burgenlandzsp layer

Comment: @Joseph: Its **your** solution, so when you post I am glad to accept it

Comment: @Kurt - Very kind of you but I just provided a tip, you did the work so I would rather you post an answer so that I can upvote it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For bigger files it is better to import them into Postgres/Postgis and let PostGIS do the heay lifting, as Joseph suggested:

```
CREATE TABLE mergedlayer 
AS SELECT ST_Union(geom) 
FROM burgenlandzsp;
```